# Bind property for ContentTemplateSelector but pass DataContext to template

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am trying to bind a `ContentPresenter` to an object which will select a template to display based on some property where the template is a sort of view on the bound object.

However, when I set up the binding as seen below, I wind up with the bound property as the `DataContext` of my `DataTemplate`s, not the owner of the property. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

The base object looks like this (I've cut out all but the relevant property):

```
public class ApplicationInterface : BaseBusinessObject, 
    IState, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Type CurrentPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (Type)_properties["CurrentPage"].Value;
        }
        set
        {
            _properties["CurrentPage"].Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I then am trying to bind to `CurrentPage` property in XAML like so:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentPage}" 
    ContentTemplateSelector={StaticResource ResourceKey=PageTemplateSelector}"/>
```

The implementation of the `DataTemplateSelector`:

```
public class PageTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, 
        DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null && item != null && item is Type)
        {
            Type t = item as Type;
            if (t == typeof(Home))
                return element.FindResource("homeTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            else if (t == typeof(ProfileEdit))
                return element.FindResource("profileTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            else if (t == typeof(WBI))
                return element.FindResource("wbiTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            else if (t == typeof(PC))
                return element.FindResource("pcTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And finally the `DataTemplate`s:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="homeTemplate">
        <pages:Home DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="profileTemplate">
        <pages:ProfileEdit DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="wbiTemplate">
        <pages:WBI DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="pcTemplate">
        <pages:PC DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up naming my window, then binding to the DataContext of it. So basically all I had to do was change the template bindings to:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="homeTemplate">
    <pages:Home DataContext="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=DataContext}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I opted for this rather than alter my business objects since the view is a purely UI construct.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Based on comments, perhaps you could try adding a Property to the pages in your DataTemplate (e.g. Parent) and then use a `RelativeSource` binding to pass in the DataContext.  Something like this:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentPage}" ContentTemplateSelector={StaticResource ResourceKey=PageTemplateSelector}" Tag="{Binding .}"/>

<DataTemplate x:Key="homeTemplate">
  <pages:Home DataContext="{Binding}" Parent="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

END EDIT

From what you're showing above, you should just be able to bind the `Content` property to the parent object:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding .}" ContentTemplateSelector={StaticResource ResourceKey=PageTemplateSelector}"/>
```

And then databind the DataTemplate to the CurrentPage property:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="homeTemplate">
    <pages:Home DataContext="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="profileTemplate">
    <pages:ProfileEdit DataContext="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="wbiTemplate">
    <pages:WBI DataContext="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="pcTemplate">
    <pages:PC DataContext="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Based on how `ContentPresenter`s work, it is behaving as expected in your example.  An alternative would be to make your model object navigable (so the CurrentPage object has a reference to its Parent ApplicationInterface) so that you can access the parent property from the context of the CurrentPage.

Comment: The current page is just a Type, it could be an enum or an int. Its simply metadata. I am looking for a way to have the `ContentPresenter` display the `DataTemplate` for whatever is in the `ApplicationInterface.CurrentPage` and the `DataTemplate` should be bound to the `ApplicationInterface`

Comment: Also, with your method when I change the value of `CurrentPage` the `ContentPresenter` binding will not update.

Comment: If you raise a `PropertyChanged` notification from the setter of the `CurrentPage` property, the `DataTemplate` will refresh.  Based on your first comment, then my only other recommendation would be to use a `RelativeSource` binding to pass in a reference to the parent, but it would require adding a common property to your Pages.  I will edit the answer above to demonstrate.

Comment: It does raise a `PropertyChanged` event, but that doesnt matter as the binding is to the `DataContext` not the `CurrentPage` property.

Comment: Oh, gotcha - your'e right.  I added another option that might work.