# Binding ContentTemplateSelector to different Object then Content (ContentPresenter)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Looking at my code I realized that many of my `DataTemplateSelector` based classes do pretty much the same thing, e.g. check a `bool` property of the bound object. I don't really want to have a bunch of objects that pretty much do the same, but I'm not entirely happy with my ideas.

The idea I like most is to bind the object I need to the Template and have my `DataTemplateSelector` have a property that can be set to the *name* of the e.g. boolean property that should be used to select the template (supplying the name when instantiating the selector in my xaml. 
In the selector I would use reflection to access the property.

The second idea would be to just bind my boolean property, and then in my templates use a relative binding to the ancestor `DataContext` and work from there. I don't like this because is seems very counter intuitive and bad to maintain.

I could just implement an interface for this purpose (so that the boolean property would always have the same name), but this would mean that I would have some code in the model that is solely for the view. Or implement the interface in a `ViewModel` and be unable to have multiple `DataTemplateSelector` doing this in the same control (without splitting into classes just for this purpose).

Just bind by name. Very simple solution, but does not really work if you want to reuse your template in multiple controls. The solution I would go for if I e.g. had a single `UserControl` where I needed the template. Just make it a resource of this `UserControl` and have a simple and maintainable solution. As long as you don't want to use your templates in multiple controls, absolutely no problem there.

Are there any other ideas that I have overlooked? Any comments to the things listed above?

#### Example code for clarification

*Beware: Since I'm not in my office, I typed the code without a compiler. Since it should illustrate this problem, compile errors etc. should not matter too much*

stripped version of the model I'm talking about:

```
public class RegisterToRead : IValueNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public bool UseName { get {...} set {...} }
}
```

One of my typical `TemplateSelector`s

```
public class RegisterToReadTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, 
        DependencyObject container)
    {
        if(item != null && item is RegisterToRead)
        {
            RegisterToRead register = (RegisterToRead)item;

            if( register.UseName)
                return element.FindResource("nameSelectionTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            else
                return element.FindResource("manualEntryTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### What I can't do, but in spirit want to

Have a `TemplateSelector` that looks like this:

```
public class BooleanTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public property DataTemplate TrueTemplate { get; set; }
    public property DataTemplate FalseTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, 
        DependencyObject container)
    {
        if(item != null && item is bool)
        {
            bool value = (bool)item;

            if( value)
                return TrueTemplate;
            else
                return FalseTemplate;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And use it like this, to achieve to effect shown above:

```
<sel:BooleanTemplateSelector
     TrueTemplate="{StaticResource nameSelectionTemplate}" 
     FalseTemplate="{StaticResource manualEntryTemplate}" 
     x:Key="RegisterToReadTemplateSelector" />
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedRegister.UseName}" 
    ContentTemplateSelector={StaticResource ResourceKey=RegisterToReadTemplateSelector}"/>
```

But I can't do this, because then the `DataContext` inside the template will be set to the UseName Property, which is not what I would want.

This question has a duplicate on stackoverflow: [Bind property for ContentTemplateSelector but pass DataContext to template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849786/bind-property-for-contenttemplateselector-but-pass-datacontext-to-template) where the OP did not get any answers, and went for the fourth idea. I wanted to restate the question to also get some feedback on the other ideas that I posted.